# Laravel 5.3 Authentication

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте, делаю shopping-cart по урокам этого [youtube-пользователя](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oc1_DHfL89k&list=PL55RiY5tL51qUXDyBqx0mKVOhLNFwwxvH&index=2), в видео используется laravel 5.2 я же сел изучать 5.3. Проблема с авторизацией.

web.php

```
 Route::get('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getSignup',
        'as' => 'user.signup'
    ])->middleware('quest');

    Route::post('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignup',
        'as' => 'user.signup'
    ])->middleware('quest');;
    Route::get('/signin', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getSignin',
        'as' => 'user.signin'
    ])->middleware('quest');
    Route::post('/signin', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignin',
        'as' => 'user.signin'
    ])->middleware('quest');
```

UserController.php

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
public function getSignup()
{
    return view('user.signup');
}

public function postSignup(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:4'
    ]);

    $user = new User([
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))
    ]);
    $user->save();
    return redirect()->route('product.index');
}

public function getSignin()
{
    return view('user.signin');
}

public function postSignin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required',
        'password' => 'required|min:4'
    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')])){
        return redirect()->route('user.profile');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Kernel.php

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

но при попытке перейти по 1 из URl (например, laravel.dev/signin) получаю вот такой expetion [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте везде в коде `quest` на `guest`, на будущее учитесь читать ошибки. В ошибке сказано, что используется неизвестный класс `quest`. Если вы такой класс не использовали нигде, то либо ваша опечатка (проверьте поиском в коде), либо какой-то класс из используемых вами библиотек например не загрузился, тогда гуглите ошибку.

Comment: Сказать стыдно- не сказать ничего.Спасибо большое.

Comment: Newakkoff начал писать проект тоже по этому видеокурсу, у меня тоже 5.3 стоит, но у меня что-то произошло намного раньше,ччем у Вас...может Вы тоже столкнулись с этим?урок #5 User Sign Up  12:50 делаю команду php artisan migrate -все хорошо...захожу на adress_site.com/signup   а оно выдает 404 (Not found)... The requested URL /signup was not found on this server.Подскажите пожалуйста!даю Вам +голос только помогите(((((